# How to get certificates for identities from CA in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When following the documentation at [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue) in order to issue identities in Hyperledger Composer, they say that:

> The Hyperledger Fabric certificate authority generates an enrollment secret that can be given to the participant, who can then use the enrollment secret to request their enrollment certificate and private keys from the Hyperledger Fabric certificate authority.

I have successfully issued an identity and got the enrollment secret. However, it is not clear how to request the certificates from the CA.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that instruction is not entirely clear, will need to get this changed.

A Business Network Card is the definitive means to connect to a Composer business network, and a constituent part of that is identity that you issued (and which was mapped to a participant in Composer) - it is only possible to access a Composer business network through a valid Business Network Card. It consists of a connection profile, some metadata for the identity using it, and ultimately, a set of credentials (certificate/private key which get populated automatically to the user's wallet from where it is used to 'connect' - a 'ping' is also a connect). FYI an identity (linked to a participant in Composer) can have one or more cards (each to connect to one or more business networks).

The document you need to read to do that is https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.identity.issue.html

you'll see it has a -f flag to create a card file - that is the file you import  (eg using Composer Playground to import or `composer card import -f` ). If you've done that import from the CLI, do a `composer network ping` so that it will use the one-time enrolment secret to request the certificate/key from the CA server and then store it in the user's wallet under $HOME/.composer - the card should be listable using the command  `composer card list`

Comment: The posted link is dead. Here's the updated link: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.identity.issue.html

Comment: the docs URL path had changed in 2018 - I've updated the post above with the new link. Thanks.